# How to add User Libraries in an Eclipse Che Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse-che

I'm currently evaluating the use of the Eclipse Che Cloud IDE as an alternative to running Eclipse Neon locally for an existing project running on Jboss.

In Eclipse Neon, under Preferences, a user library can be created under Java-> Build Path->User Libraries. However Eclispe Che only provides the option to add one Jar at a time.

Is there a way to create user libraries in Che, add multiple jars to the library, then add the library to the project's Java Build Path?

Answer (score 0):

Che workspaces have a Meven .m2 dir at `/home/user/.m2`.  Assuming you have a maven .m2 directory on the host system (the one running docker), you can use
[volume mounts](http://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/devops/volume-mounts/index.html) to mount external directories into the workspace. Uncomment the `CHE_WORKSPACE_VOLUME` in your `che.env` file and add the path you want mapped.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, mavenizing your project is the best way to go with Eclipse Che. You simply declare your deps in pom.xml, and Che Maven Plugin will update project classpath and instruct content assist about project dependencies.